# How to decrement numbers in JSON file until 0?

Tags: discord.js

i have a JSON file and it has mutes for a specific staff member
and i want to decrement it until 0
how can i do that?

also i want a code to decrement all staff members mutes

```
client.on('message', message => {

  if(!staffstats[message.author.id]) staffstats[message.author.id] = {
    mutes: 0,
    bans: 0,
    warns: 0,
    tickets: 0,
    appeals: 0,
    vips: 0,
    WarnedTimes: 0
  }

  if(message.content === prefix + "mutes-reset"){
    user = message.mentions.users.first();

    staffstats[user.id].mutes--;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close! You are able to do `staffstats[user.id].mutes = staffstats[user.id].mutes - 1;`, however, you do ask for *until 0*, so a simple check before changing the value will suffice:

```
if (!staffstats[user.id].mutes <= 0) //if mutes value is NOT lower or equal to 0, do:
  staffstats[user.id].mutes = staffstats[user.id].mutes - 1; //reduces current value of mutes by 1
```

To `decrement all staff members mutes`, you will need to know who the staff are, and their IDs. Assuming you know this, you can loop through an array of the user ids for instance.

If you are solely storing all the values of all staff members in objects (`{}`), then you can do `Object.keys(staffstats);` for all the keys (those are the user ids) because it's conveniently in an array that you can loop through.

```
var staffId = ['12345', '23456', '34567']; //this is just an example array
staffId.forEach(id => { //loop through array of staffId, storing value in id variable
  //same method as above
  if (!staffstats[id].mutes <= 0)
    staffstats[id].mutes = staffstats[id].mutes - 1;
};
```

Comment: `staffstats[id].mutes = staffstats[id].mutes - 1` can be shortened to `staffstats[id].mutes--`.